# Ruby: Undefined method 'length' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, methods, undefined, nomethoderror

I am attempting to write a program that takes in a string and outputs the longest word in that string. Now, I know that my code looks pretty hairy but I am pretty new to the Ruby language so please just bear with me. I don't understand any of the other explanations given regarding this issue. I am not looking for the answer. All I want is for a kind human being to please explain to me why my program halts at line 16 with the problem stated in the title of this question. Please and thank you!

```ruby
# longest_word.rb
# A method that takes in a string and returns the longest word
# in the string. Assume that the string contains only
# letters and spaces. I have used the String 'split' method to
# aid me in my quest. Difficulty: easy.

def longest_word(sentence)
  array = sentence.split(" ")

  idx = 0
  ordered_array = []

  puts(array.length)

  while idx <= array.length
    if (array[idx].length) < (array[idx + 1].length)
      short_word = array[idx]
      ordered_array.push(short_word)
      idx += 1
    elsif array[idx].length > array[idx + 1].length
      long_word = array[idx]
      ordered_array.unshift(long_word)
      idx += 1
    else l_w = ordered_array[0]
      return l_w
    end
  end
end

puts("\nTests for #longest_word")
puts(longest_word("hi hello goodbye"))
```

Comment: Please include a minimal code example in the body of your post. Images are not a great help, since we can't copy them into our own environments and run them.

Comment: When you post an image of your code, instead of posting your code, you force people to type it all in order to help you. Do you really think this is a nice attitude?

Comment: ...and links are meant to be broken. Post the code here and it will live forever. These suggestions are for you to edit your question and replace the link with your code.

Comment: @EddeAlmeida l apologize, I am a noob to stack overflow. I'll include the code from this day forward.

Comment: Thanks. We want to help, so help us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

At some point in your while loop, you come to a state where idx is pointing to the last item in the array. At that point, asking for `array[idx+1]` returns nil, and NilClass does not have a method 'length'

The simple fix would be to change the while loop condition so that `idx+1` is always within the array.

Answer (score 0):

May I recommend a shorter solution.

```
words1= "This is a sentence."  # The sentence

words2 = words1.split(/\W+/)  # splits the words by via the space character

words3 = words2.sort_by {|x| x.length} #sort the array

words3[-1] #gets the last word
```

or

```
def longest_word(sentence)
 sentence.split(/\W+/).sort_by {|x| x.length}[-1]
end
```